# ¿Cómo acceder a una función contenida en una Master Page desde una Web Form?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Quiero acceder a una función que tengo dentro de una Master Page, el acceso a la función lo quiero hacer desde una  Web Form.

Comment: ¿A qué le llamas "WebMaster" y "web Content"?

Comment: @Davlio es "Master Page" y "Web Form"

Comment: ¿Cuál es el método al que quieres acceder y de que evento de tu formulario quieres acceder? ¿Cómo se llama la clase de tu MasterPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se crea una inteface, que contenga la firma de los métodos de la masterpage, por ej: IMiMasterpage
La Masterpage implementará esa interfaz (añadimos el implemenets correspondiente)
Hacemos un cast del master (desde el webusercontrol) a la interfaz, y ya tenemos acceso a sus métodos!!
  ((IMiMasterpage)this.Page.Master).hazmLaCena();

El problema es que desde el ascx, no se porque..., no se puede hacer un cast directo al tipo de la masterpage (directamente el tipo no aparece).

Sea como sea... problema resuelto